# Issue with camera tracking in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm following a youtube tutorial that uses a tile-map. A camera that tracks the player moving horizontally was added and I implemented a vertical camera as well, these both work well. The issue I'm having is that the player spawns in the bottom left-hand corner of the map off-screen, while the camera view starts in the top left-hand corner. Therefore at the beginning of the game I have to wait a few seconds for the camera to slowly move down screen to get the player in view. My question is how do I get the camera to start with the player already in view? Thanks in advance

Tile Class:

```
class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self,image, pos,size):
    super().__init__()
    file = pygame.image.load(image)
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(file, (96, 96))
    
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(bottomleft = pos)
    

def update(self,x_shift, y_shift):
    self.rect.x += x_shift
    self.rect.y += y_shift
```

Scroll Function:

```
def scroll(self):
    player = self.player.sprite
    player_x = player.rect.centerx
    player_y = player.rect.centery
    direction_x = player.direction.x

    if player_x < screen_width / 4 and direction_x < 0:
        self.world_shift_x = 8
        player.speed = 0
    elif player_x > screen_width - (screen_width / 4) and direction_x > 0:
        self.world_shift_x = -8
        player.speed = 0
    else:
        self.world_shift_x = 0
        player.speed = 8

    if player_y < screen_height / 4 :
        self.world_shift_y = 8
        
    elif player_y > screen_height - (screen_height / 4):
        self.world_shift_y = -8
        
    else:
        self.world_shift_y = 0
```

Update level:

```
self.tiles.update(self.world_shift_x, self.world_shift_y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize `world_shift_x` and `world_shift_y` and shift the tiles once before running the application loop. Run the following code before the application loop

```py
self.world_shift_x = screen_width // 2 - player.rect.centerx
self.world_shift_y = screen_height // 2 - player.rect.centery
self.tiles.update(self.world_shift_x, self.world_shift_y)
player.rect.centerx = screen_width // 2
player.rect.centery = screen_height // 2
```